# Remove all characters after specific character in multiple filenames

Tags: powershell, file-rename, batch-rename

how do I remove every character after a _ in folder names
ex
folder names
307456_ajksndkajsdna_asd_busd to 307456

780451_dsadafg_4565 to 780451

edit: also remove the _
I am using windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell, you can use the [`-split` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx) to split the string by `_` and keep only the first part:

```
$number,$null = '307456_ajksndkajsdna_asd_busd' -split '_'
```

The value of `$number` is now `307456`, the rest has been discarded.

If you want to rename all child folders in a folder to just the first number, use `Get-ChildItem` to retrieve the files, and `Rename-Item` to rename them:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder\name |Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.Name -split '_')[0] }
```

Comment: Seems like I need to add the name of every single file using this method. I have hundreds of files that are sorted like this. Numbers_combination of numbers and letters__combination of numbers and letters__combination of numbers and letters. I want to remove the first "_" and everything after it.

Comment: Do you just want a list of the preceding numbers, or do you want to rename the files?

Comment: I want to rename all the folders to just the first numbers before the first _ just like the examples above

Comment: Your last edit did not work instead it added the first numbers before the _ in front of the old file name from 307456_ajksndkajsdna_asd_busd to 307456307456_ajksndkajsdna_asd_busd. Also I didnt add an extension at the end of the code because I am changing the name of folders not files. so I wrote Get-ChildItem -Path C: \xxxxxxx |Rename-Item -NewName { $($_.BaseName -split '_')[
0] + $_ }

Comment: That happened because you removed `.Extension` - `$_` will evaluate to the full file/folder name. Sorry, I missed the folder vs. file bit, I've update the answer to only rename folders

Comment: How would you do this for all files within a particular folder? Instead of renaming folders, I'd like to rename the files. Basically, strip anything after (and including) the first "dash" character.

Comment: @Garconis Change the `{$_.PSIsContainer}` predicate to the opposite (so, `{-not $_.PSIsContainer}`)